# How to properly relate tables with multiple keys in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many

I am looking for a way to relate two tables that have multiple keys in a one-to-many relationship. I have the following entities, and perhaps it is a poorly designed example, but nevertheless:

Item

```
@Id
@Column(name = "item_id", columnDefinition = "INT(11)")
private Long itemId;

@Id
@Column(name = "name", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)")
private String name;

@Column(name = "price", columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(12, 2)")
private Double price;
```

Order

```
@Id
@Column(name = "order_id", columnDefinition = "INT(11)")
private Long orderId;

@Id
@Column(name = "order_number", columnDefinition = "INT(11)")
private Long orderNumber;


@Column(name = "date", columnDefinition = "DATE")
private Date date;

@Column(name = "item_count", columnDefinition = "INT(11)")
private Long itemCount;
```

I need to establish a one-to-many relationship between these entities such that Order contains multiple Items.

My requirement is for the eventual Orders table structure to contain the following fields:

```
order_id,
order_number,
date,
item_count,
item_id
```

In order to relate Item (one-side) to Order (many-side), i have to do the following

Item

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="item")
private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
```

Order

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "name")
})
private Item item;
```

This compiles, but now my Orders table contains a field called "name", which i am trying to avoid. How can i relate the tables only by the item_id and not the item_id + name ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you several things:

### Use surrogate key

Each entity should have only one `@Id` annotation.
Even if your domain has a natural composite key - use generated (surrogate) key.

Except it is widely used pattern, it also **solves your problem with `item_id` + `name` relations**.

### Avoid bidirectional mapping

Bidirectional mappings drastically increase code complexity and reduce maintainability. Moreover, in almost all cases it is not needed and can be easily removed.

### Avoid lazy loading

If you need to load only `Orders` without `Items` make them independent without any lazyness (do not use `@OneToMany` mapping).

If in most cases you use them together - load items eagerly.

Doing this way you avoid 'SessionClosedException' attempting to call usual POJO getter.